# line height option is not show in ckeditor even add the plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ckeditor

[image][image]I have download same extra plugins and past the plugins into plugins folder. ckeditor/plugins/lineheight and ckeditor/plugins/language.
And enable in config.js. But so for the line height and language option is not show in ckeditor.

```
config.extraPlugins = 'lineheight';
config.extraPlugins = 'language';
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
};
```

Comment: might be caching issue. CKEditor is bad at caching..

Comment: I  clear the browser data and check all the browser. But so for not display the line height option. I am trying this http://ckeditor.com/addon/lineheight

Answer (score 3):

By doing a double assignment

```
config.extraPlugins = 'lineheight';
config.extraPlugins = 'language';
```

you basically override `config.extraPlugins` property, so it equals `'language'`. Do this instead:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'lineheight,language';
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but I just want to share the solution for future reference.

Assuming that you added extraPlugin correctly, you will also need the following in your config:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here.
    // For complete reference see:
    // https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html

    // The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for a single toolbar row.
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
        { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
        { name: 'forms' },
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
        { name: 'links' },
        { name: 'insert' },
        { name: 'styles' },
        { name: 'colors' },
        { name: 'tools' },
        { name: 'others' },
        { name: 'about' }
    ];

    // The default plugins included in the basic setup define some buttons that
    // are not needed in a basic editor. They are removed here.
    config.removeButtons = 'Cut,Copy,Paste,Undo,Redo,Anchor,Underline,Strike,Subscript,Superscript';

    // Dialog windows are also simplified.
    config.removeDialogTabs = 'link:advanced';
};
```

Most of the options are optional but { name: 'styles' } is required.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure

lineheight is not mentioned in config.removeButtons in \ckeditor\config.js

```
config.removeButtons ="lineheight"
```

Answer (score -2):

```
config.extraPlugins = 'lineheight, language';
config.line_height = "1px;1.1px;1.2px;1.3px;1.4px;1.5px";

Toolbar : { 
    name: 'styles', 
    items: [ 'Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize','lineheight' ] 
},
```

Comment: @SukhadaKedare Hello and welcome to SO, thank you for trying to answer this question, however, some explanations would be nice.